# Short story about a farmer who buries the body of a crashed alien, which then grows into a new body

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In [a comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIooFVe5-Ek&lc=Ugx6oO2HJ_mHtV7P2UV4AaABAg.9PrHSsHnoiy9QBztwK0eMJ) in a Q&A with the director of the excellent short science fiction film *Laura un Vineta*, a fellow called Will Long tried to identify a short story which was probably from the '50s or '60s:

> Your video brought to mind a science fiction short story that I read more than fifty years ago. An alien ship crashed in the cornfield of a lonely, but kindhearted farmer. The farmer finds and buries the crushed body of the sole occupant. Somewhat resembling a corn plant itself, the creature is regenerated from the burial site. And the farmer takes it into his home and raises it to maturity; whereupon, the alien repairs it ship and leaves to return to its home world. However, before it departs, it removes something resembling a large, gem-like marble from its own body and leaves it with the farmer. Even though it knew its own journey through the interstellar distances would be harder to endure without its "companion" (the gem), the alien gave it to the kind farmer to ease his loneliness.

> I actually thought it was called "The Companion" or something similar. However, my browser searches on science fiction of that theme did not produce the result I had hoped. It was popular enough that the story later appeared in a book anthology—I read it first in one of the 1950's or early 60's pulp magazines such as "Analog" or "Galaxy"—and I read it again about twenty years ago.

I had a bit of a look myself, but there are too many well-known stories involving aliens and farmers that aren't this!

Comment: I've read that one before... let me see if I can find it. My impulse is that it's a Ben Bova story, but I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I just linked to your previous identification below.  Apparently, I asked the question last time.

Comment: ^_^ No wonder it seemed familiar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeking a story where a dead alien regrows as a plant from its grave](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174405/seeking-a-story-where-a-dead-alien-regrows-as-a-plant-from-its-grave)

Comment: @TomAnderson: I think it's highly likely we've found your story. If you can confirm it, we would appreciate it. :)

Comment: @tardigrade - You should only vote to close story-ID questions as duplicates if both have the same answer _and_ both answers are confirmed to be correct by the authors of each question. The answer posted here has not been confirmed to be correct yet, and until it is, this thread should remain open.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots and team: it seems overwhelmingly likely that you have indeed got it! I will get back to Mr Long and try to confirm it. If i can't get a response from him in a reasonable time, i'll come back and accept.

Comment: [My reply](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIooFVe5-Ek&lc=Ugx6oO2HJ_mHtV7P2UV4AaABAg.9PrHSsHnoiy9TPp6I72dvS). I thought i posted a reply yesterday, but either i didn't, or it's been deleted.

Comment: [That was it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIooFVe5-Ek&lc=Ugx6oO2HJ_mHtV7P2UV4AaABAg.9PrHSsHnoiy9Uw7YctuOIs). Apologies for the immensely delayed reply.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is "[A Death in the House](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1959-10/page/n83/)," by Clifford D. Simak.  Since its first publication in 1959, it has [appeared in numerous anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41497).

Summarized [here:](https://www.patreon.com/posts/death-in-house-d-35484374)

> In "A Death in the House," Mose Abrams, an irascible old farmer comes across a crashed spaceship and a dying alien.  He tries to get help for the alien, but nobody does anything for it.  When the alien dies, Mose buries it.  He doesn't tell anyone where he buried it, and he also doesn't let them know about the remains of the spaceship.  At which point, the dead alien sprouts back up from where it was buried, and with Mose's help repairs its spaceship.  Those repairs use up the store of silver that Mose kept beneath the floorboards of his house, which had been his only companion and comfort.  When the alien leaves, he gives Mose a small glowing crystal.  The gift makes Mose happy, even though he doesn't know why.

At the end of the story (the last two paragraphs of the story are from the alien's point of view) the gift is indeed called a "Companion."

Comment: Duplicate of here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174405/seeking-a-story-where-a-dead-alien-regrows-as-a-plant-from-its-grave/