# A short story within an anthology... A crashed alien is buried by a recluse

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The alien grows like a plant and the recluse has kept the original alien's damaged craft. The regrown alien needs silver to repair the damage.  The recluse parts with his stash of silver dollars, the craft is repaired, and the new alien departs leaving his companion as payment.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This sounds like an interesting story. I would suggest taking a look at our [tour] and [help], specifically [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/57310) and add any other details you can think of. This will help our ID experts get you the answer you are looking for!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[A Death in the House](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41497) by Clifford D. Simak

It ends

> It was dark and lonely and unending in the depths of space with no Companion. It might be long before another was available.
>
> It perhaps was a foolish thing to do, but the old creature had been such a kind savage, so fumbling and so pitiful and eager to help. And one who travels far and fast must likewise travel light. There had been nothing else to give.

Also the answer to these old questions

- [Short story about a farmer who buries the body of a crashed alien, which then grows into a new body](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254816/short-story-about-a-farmer-who-buries-the-body-of-a-crashed-alien-which-then-gr/254818#254818) (duplicate)
- [Seeking a story where a dead alien regrows as a plant from its grave](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174405/seeking-a-story-where-a-dead-alien-regrows-as-a-plant-from-its-grave) (primary)